# Meteor collection update giving access denied 403 error

Tags: android, meteor

I have implememted 'com.github.delight-im:Android-DDP:v3.3.0' in Android native app it works fine. But when I logout and login again I get this error:

```
03-08 18:38:53.392 8051-15581/trivialapps.com.oddup I/System.out: Meteor
03-08 18:38:53.392 8051-15581/trivialapps.com.oddup I/System.out: onTextMessage
03-08 18:38:53.392 8051-15581/trivialapps.com.oddup I/System.out: payload == {"msg":"result","id":"3cca7039-800e-49eb-93aa-963c1fecbb9e","error":{"error":403,"reason":"Access denied","message":"Access denied [403]","errorType":"Meteor.Error"}}
```

For logout user I used below code:

```
MeteorSingleton.getInstance().logout();

if(MeteorSingleton.getInstance().isConnected())
    MeteorSingleton.getInstance().disconnect();
```

for login user I used below code:

this is the login method used:

```
 MeteorSingleton.getInstance().loginWithEmail(" giving email", "giving password", new ResultListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String s) {
                //navigating to activity
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String s, String s1, String s2) {


            }
        });
```

Please help me to solve out this error. Thank you so much.

Comment: Could you post the code you are using for login?

Comment: @BrunnoVodolaMartins i have updated login code also please see it.

Comment: for what I see, you have a Meteor problem. That may be silly, but check the email/password. Also, are you using the insecure package?
But anyway, I also see that you call .disconnect() after the logout. Are you reconnecting to the DDP server before you try to login again?

Comment: @BrunnoVodolaMartins I'm giving correct username and password I call ,disconnect after log out if connection is still establish for disconnecting